# UWP app signing certificate

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

How much time does Visual Studio 2015 take for generating signing certificate of Universal Window Apps? Its been running for past two days at my end.

Comment: Thats for sure way too long. Do you use a selfsigned certificate?

Comment: you should use vs 2017 anyways, all new support of uwp is in vs 2017 , and not with vs 2015.

Comment: @SebastianL No, I am not using selfsigned certificate. I found on Internet if I create build package to upload to the Window store, the app will be signed by Microsoft.

Comment: @ShubhamGupta If you don't use the selfsigned certificate, the vs will create a temporary certificate when you create your UWP, so what are you doing to generate signing certificate?